# iPhone developer program count-down

Tags: iphone

I am little bit confus about the iPhone developer program.

I know its One year subscription program after that we have to re-new it

Q : From which time the count down of iPhone developer program starts ?

- from the Enrolment time or
- from the application submission time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple**: The iPhone Developer Program begins from the enrollment time, and ends one year afterward.